# A cyclic homogeneous inequality in three variables involving 4th root radicals

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, radicals

*Problem (by Baoqian Liu)*: Let $x, y, z \ge 0$ with $x+y+z > 0$. Prove that
\begin{align}
&\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \sqrt[4]
{[2(x+y)^2+2(y+z)^2-(x+z)^2][2(y+z)^2+2(x+z)^2-(x+y)^2]}\\
\ge \ & \frac{9}{4}\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}
\sqrt{\frac{x(x+y)(x+z)(x+y+z)}{(2x+y+z)^2}}
+ \frac{63}{8}\sqrt{\frac{xyz}{x+y+z}}.
\end{align}
Clearly, when $x=y=z$, the inequality holds with equality.
Also, if $x=y$ and $z=0$, the inequality holds with equality.

My attempt: WLOG, assume that $x+y+z = 3$ (homogeneity) and $x\ge y\ge z$ (symmetry).

If $z \ge (\frac{2}{5})^4 = 0.0256$: Since $2(x+y)^2+2(y+z)^2-(x+z)^2 = 4y(x+y+z)+(z-x)^2 \ge 4y(x+y+z)$
and $(x+y)(x+z) \le \frac{(2x+y+z)^2}{4}$, it suffices to prove that
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \sqrt[4]
{[4y(x+y+z)][4z(x+y+z)]}
\ge  \frac{9}{8}\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}
\sqrt{x(x+y+z)}
+ \frac{63}{8}\sqrt{\frac{xyz}{x+y+z}}$$
or
$$6(\sqrt[4]{xy}+\sqrt[4]{yz}+\sqrt[4]{zx})
\ge  \frac{27}{8}(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}) + \frac{63}{8}\sqrt{xyz}.$$
Let $x=a^4, y=b^4, z=c^4$. It suffices to prove that, for $a\ge c, b\ge c, c\ge \frac{2}{5}$ with $a^4+b^4+c^4=3$,
$$48(ab+bc+ca) \ge 27(a^2+b^2+c^2) + 63a^2b^2c^2.$$
This inequality is true. I verified it by Mathematica.

Any comments are welcome.

Comment: My comment : +1

Comment: @GiangNguyễnĐặngThanh Thank you!